# How can I have two accordion buttons open on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm using a product plug in for wordpress and I'm trying to make it so that the accordion menus are both open on page load. I'm not familiar with javascript enough to mess around with it. Here is the script that is changing the accordion menus

```
if($wrapper.find('.mspc-accordion').size() > 0) {

        //accordion
        if( !$this.hasClass('active') ) {

            $menuItems.children('.icon').removeClass('minus').addClass('add');
            $this.children('.icon').removeClass('add').addClass('minus');

            var time = 300;
            $content.slideUp(time);
            $this.next('.mspc-content:first').delay(time).slideDown(time);

        }

    }
    else {

        //steps, tabs
        $content.find('.mspc-variations').hide();
        jQuery($this.data('target')).show();

    }

    $menuItems.removeClass('active');
    $this.addClass('active');


    evt.preventDefault();

});
```

Comment: Please post the entire code.

Comment: The entire site? There's a lot of css and html on just this one page. I'm asking about what this code is doing and how to make it open both at the same time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a quick look and tried this on the MSPC Hoodie preview page. It works, but one caveat though, If you press on the item heading it will slide up and then down again.

This is just a one way to give you an idea on how to get started

```
jQuery(function($) {

  $(".mspc-accordion").children(".mspc-menu-item").each( function(i ,e) {

   //this will open all accordion items, it seems that if an item has the class
   //active, it wont close unless another inactive heading is clicked

        $(e).hasClass("active") ? $(e).removeClass("active") : null;
        $(e).children('.icon').removeClass('minus').addClass('add');
        $(e).children('.icon').removeClass('add').addClass('minus');
        $(e).next('.mspc-content:first').css("display","block");

   });

});
```

Comment: Is there a way I can preview this on the MSPC Hoodie page?

Comment: You can go to your browser's console and paste this code in. For example, If youre using Chrome. Right click on the page, click inspect, go to the Console tab and paste this code in